# Can not compile a stored procedure because it seems to be locked

Tags: oracle, toad, locks

I am working with a stored procedure in Oracle. I was debugging it and for some reason, my Toad hanged and I had to end the process. As a result, if I want to re-compile the stored procedure, it takes for ever just like when an object is locked.

I tried finding locks using the sysadmin, but I am not being able to find the right query to get the lock. I want to kill the process that is locking the stored procedure .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the status to confirm your session is still running which is not allowing you to recompile procedure:

```
SELECT sid, serial#, status FROM v$session;
```

Execute the below script which will print out sqls, which should be executed.

```
SELECT 'ALTER SYSTEM KILL SESSION '''||sid||','||serial#||''' IMMEDIATE;' 
FROM v$session 
where username='YOUR_USER';
```

**Note:** If you want to kill all the sessions,the above script will prepare all small scripts.

Then try to re-compile your stored procedure.